# Unreal Engine 4 how do I publish my game to a website?

Tags: html, web, unreal-engine4

I just made a game in Unreal Engine 4 and wanted it to put it on my personal website. I was wondering how to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will want to package the game, then upload your code to a directory on your server.

Packaging:
[UE4 Getting started HTML5 Projects](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/HTML5/GettingStarted/index.html)

If you don't have a server you can get one for fairly cheap from godaddy, hostgator, hostbuddy etc, there are many options.

Once you upload it to your server from the admin console of your site, simply go to the directory you uploaded it to.

www.myserver.com/MyProject.html

Hope this helped.